# Print result from reduce in Highland.js

Tags: node.js, stream, reactive-programming, frp, highland.js

I written a simple script which should count line

```
var
  H = require('highland'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  split = require('split');

var lineStream = fs.createReadStream('data-samples/sample.log').pipe(split());

H('data', lineStream).reduce(0, function(count) {
  return count + 1;
}).each(console.log);
```

But for some reasons I see nothing in console. Documentation says about [lazyness](http://highlandjs.org/#laziness) but `each` call should "invoke" the stream. How to fix the issue?

**NB:** It's a question about highland.js and not about a way to count lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'reduce' stream only emits the [final value](http://highlandjs.org/#async). you should provide [_.nil](http://highlandjs.org/#nil) as final value for Highland Stream. like this:

```
lineStream.on('end', function() { s.write(H.nil) });
```

Also Highland.js [natively supports Node streams](http://highlandjs.org/#_(source)), so you don't need create event stream. use:

```
H(lineStream)
```

instead

```
H('data', lineStream)
```